# Count distinct sets of a send/receive pair

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a table keeping track of messages sent between users of our app. Each row has a `fromid`, `toid`, `messageid`, and `datetime`.

I want to count distinct pairs of users communicating with each other. Another way to put this is to count distinct "conversations" between users, where a conversation is simply defined as 1 or more messages sent between two users. So, to give a concrete example, a conversation might be Fred sending 2 messages to Bob, and Bob sending 3 messages to Fred.

```
fromid toid messageid datetime
Fred Bob 123 2013-04-22 00:00:01
Bob Fred 135 2013-04-22 00:01:02
Fred Bob 238 2013-04-22 00:05:00
Bob Fred 300 2013-04-22 00:09:13
Bob Fred 312 2013-04-22 00:10:48
```

All this would be 1 conversation. What is an efficient way of doing a query for this (the table is very large)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT LEAST(fromID, toID), GREATEST(fromID, toID)) TotalConversation
FROM   messages
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee8dd/7)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*added one new record*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/142d6f/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔═══════════════════╗
║ TOTALCONVERSATION ║
╠═══════════════════╣
║                 1 ║
╚═══════════════════╝
```

Comment: Thanks! This is much more efficient than what I was planning to do (self-joins, yada, yada). Very clever.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a little trick involving `CONCAT` function, such as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(fromid, '-', toid) AS 'conversation',
       fromid,
       toid,
       ...
  FROM table_name
 WHERE ...
```

Answer (score -1):

In MYSQL, that would be

```
select count(distinct greatest(fromid, toid) + ':' + least(fromid, toid)) from messages;
```

But, I don't think there is efficient way to do it for the whole table in one query.